# My Nextpage Button is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, redirect

i have 3 buttons in my VF page when i click it should open (profile setting and logout buttons are working) But next page button  is not working

This is my VF Code

```
<apex:page controller="ProfileLogoutControllerQ2" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
<style>
   body{ background-color:papayawhip;}
</style>
<apex:form > 
<html>
<head>
<title>Questionnaire2</title>
 <style>
       div.btnGroup{
      text-align: center;margin-top:125px;margin-right:250px;padding:8px*20px;
       }

      div.btnGroup1{
      text-align:right;margin-top:-24px;margin-right:450px;padding:8px*20px;
       }

     div.btnGroup2{
     text-align:left;margin-top:160px;margin-left:125px;padding:8px*20px;font-size:150%
      }

     div.btnGroup3{
     text-align:center;margin-top:25px;margin-right:10px;padding:8px*20px;
     }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="btnGroup">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Profilesetting}" value="Profile setting" styleClass="buttonStyle"  style="background:thistle ;width:130px;height:25px;font-size: 14px"/>
    </div>    
<div class="btnGroup1">    
  <apex:commandButton action="{!Logout}" value="Logout" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:thistle ;width:130px;height:25px;font-size: 14px"/>
</div>

       <div class="btnGroup2">  
      <label for="Feed Back">YOUR FEEDBACK <br/><br/><br/></label> 
      <form method="post" action="/admin/member-modify-{$member->id}">
      <label for="Feed Back">1. Are you satisfied with the cleanliness of the facility?:<br /> </label><br /><br />
      <select name="sel_state" class="validate" id="sel_state">
        <option value="None">None</option>
         <option value="poor" >poor</option>
         <option value="average">average</option>
         <option value="good">good</option>
         <option value="excellent">excellent</option>
          </select><br /><br />
          <input type="Free text" value=" " name=" " size="30"/><br /><br />
          <input name="submit" value="Submit" id="member_state_submit" type="submit" class="submit" Onclick="showClose();" /><br /><br />
           </form>
    </div>




     <script>
        function showClose() {
            var val = document.getElementById('sel_state').value;
            if (val=='poor') {
                var state = confirm ("You have rated cleanliness Facility is Poor");
            } else if (val=='average') {
                var state = confirm ("You have rated cleanliness Facility is Average");
            } else if(val=='good') {
                var state = confirm ("You have rated cleanliness Facility is good");
             }
               else if (val=='excellent'){
                var state = confirm ("You have rated cleanliness Facility is Excellent");
}
}
    </script>

   <div class="btnGroup3">          
    <apex:commandButton action="{!NextPage}" value="Next page" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:lightcoral ;width:120px;height:25px;font-size: 13px"/>    
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This is my Controller

```
public class ProfileLogoutControllerQ2 {

public  PageReference Profilesetting(){

        // create case, etc.

        system.debug('test');

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/00e?setupid=EnhancedProfiles&retURL=%2Fui%2Fsetup%2FSetup%3Fsetupid%3DUsers'); 
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }
public  PageReference Logout(){

        // create case, etc.

        system.debug('test');

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/secur/logout.jsp'); 
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }
    public  PageReference NextPage(){

        // create case, etc.

        system.debug('test');

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/Questionnaire3?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1'); 
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Could any one please help me out from this issues

Answer (score -1):

Now i got the answer

i Just Removed it from my Vf Page Now its working

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/member-modify-{$member->id}">
```

Comment: Ah, the submit action might be overriding with HTML form element.